# List from spring controller not converting to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, arraylist, jackson

I am returning a list from controller . This the javascript code :-

```
gets.push($.get("getImageLocationByAdId?adId="+advertisement.adId,function(images,status){
                        advertisement.images=images;
                       // advertisement.firstImageLocation=images[0].location;
                       console.log(images);//works fine
                       console.log(images[0]); //undefined
                    }));
```

As wriiten in the code `images[0]` is undefined . On the other hand in the console it looks like an array . How to solve this problem ?

Comment: My guess is you're getting a plain string, not array. You need to parse the string into array.

Comment: If you believe that the problem is with your Spring controller, then please post its code too.

Comment: can you try `console.log(images['0']);`

Comment: I think I found the answer . The controller is returning empty arrays in some cases . That is why images[0] is undefined.